# Alter and Optimize sql query

Tags: mysql

I need to please change this SQL query to NOT use sub-query with IN, I need for this query to work faster.

here is the query i am working on. About 7 million rows.

```
SELECT `MovieID`, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM `download`
WHERE `UserID` IN (
SELECT `UserID` FROM `download`
   WHERE `MovieID` = 995
)
GROUP BY `MovieID`
ORDER BY `Count` DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this - but (in the event that you switch to an OUTER JOIN) make sure you're counting the right thing...

```
 SELECT MovieID
      , COUNT(*) ttl
   FROM download x
   JOIN download y
     ON y.userid = x.userid
    AND y.movieid = 995
  GROUP 
     BY x.MovieID
  ORDER  
     BY ttl DESC;
```

Comment: I've seen many queries from your history, and pretty on-target with OP.  Only drawback, maybe for future, expand to the user so they understand WHY things work a certain way will help them and others so they LEARN how to do in the future vs just cut/paste... Just constructive criticism, but again, you are on target with posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) instead, see [Optimizing Subqueries with EXISTS Strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html):

> Consider the following subquery comparison:
>
> outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ... WHERE subquery_where) MySQL
>   evaluates queries “from outside to inside.” That is, it first obtains
>   the value of the outer expression outer_expr, and then runs the
>   subquery and captures the rows that it produces.
>
> A very useful optimization is to “inform” the subquery that the only
>   rows of interest are those where the inner expression inner_expr is
>   equal to outer_expr. This is done by pushing down an appropriate
>   equality into the subquery's WHERE clause. That is, the comparison is
>   converted to this:
>
> EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE subquery_where AND
>   outer_expr=inner_expr) After the conversion, MySQL can use the
>   pushed-down equality to limit the number of rows that it must examine
>   when evaluating the subquery.

Comment: can u explain this by writing query. It is still very confusing for me

Answer (score -2):

filter direct on movieId..you does not need to add sub query. it can be done by using movieID =995 in where clause.

```
SELECT `MovieID`, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM `download`
WHERE  `MovieID` = 995
GROUP BY `MovieID`
ORDER BY `Count` DESC
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original query. He asks for all the movies of any user that has downloaded a given movie.

Comment: This query will only contain a single MovieID (995) in the result set. This is not what is happening in the original query.

Comment: The OP said `change this SQL query to NOT use sub-query`. The OP's query also fetch those with MovieID=995

Comment: @ling.s **no**. The OP query uses the subquery to get UserIDs and the outer query finds all movies of those users..

Comment: @ling.s see the answer by user Strawberry for how the original query can be written without a sub-query